# Importing a WebService:

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm trying to import the following web service: http://www.biomart.org/biomart/martwsdl

Using **curl** for the service **getResistry()** : everything is OK:

```
curl --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' --data '<?xml version="1.0"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mar="http://www.biomart.org:80/MartServiceSoap">
<soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mar:getRegistry/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>' http://www.biomart.org:80/biomart/martsoap
```

it returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.o
rg/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/
envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getRegistryResponse xmlns="http://www.biomart.org:80/MartServiceSoap">
      <mart>
        <name xsi:type="xsd:string">ensembl</name>
        <displayName xsi:type="xsd:string">ENSEMBL GENES 57 (SANGER UK)</displayName>
        <database xsi:type="xsd:string">ensembl_mart_57</database>
(...)
```

OK.

But when this service is generated using **CXF/wsdl2java** ( or even wsimport)

```
mkdir src
wsdl2java -keep -d src -client "http://www.biomart.org/biomart/martwsdl"
javac -g -d src -sourcepath src src/org/biomart/_80/martservicesoap/MartServiceSoap_BioMartSoapPort_Client.java
java -cp src org.biomart._80.martservicesoap.MartServiceSoap_BioMartSoapPort_Client
```

the generated client returns an **empty** list for **getRegistry**():

```
Invoking getRegistry...
getRegistry.result=[]
```

why ? what should I do, to make this code work ?

Many thanks

Pierre

Comment: Please show the code in MartServiceSoap_BioMartSoapPort_Client.java, the main method in particular followed by the place where you are invoking the service.

Comment: @shivaspk  MartServiceSoap_BioMartSoapPort_Client.java was generated by CXF/wsdl2java using the '-client' option.

Comment: Its only a stub class what it generates, all it does is create java equivalents of the WSDL operations, you need to write a simple java program to invoke the getRegitry() operation.

Answer (score 0):

In the client class have a main method in which you invoke getRegistry operation.

It may look like this

```
MartServiceSoap_BioMartSoapPort_Client client = new MartServiceSoap_BioMartSoapPort_Client();
System.out.println(client.getRegistry());
```

Comment: Sorry and forgot to mention and then compile & run this client class using javac and java.

Comment: sorry but the client genrated by CXF/wsdl2java **does** generate a **main** method and the code contains a call to getRegistry().      

java.util.List&lt;org.biomart._80.martservicesoap.Mart&gt; _getRegistry__return = port.getRegistry();
System.out.println("getRegistry.result=" + _getRegistry__return);